# Bitwise condition in df.loc doesn't give expect result

Tags: python, pandas, bit-manipulation, pandas-loc

I wrote the following code :

```
df.loc[((df['col_A'] == False) & (df['loc_B'] == False)), 'col_C'] = "abc"
```

but "abc" gets written on all the values of col_C instead of the ones specified in the condition. Why is that ?

Edit:

My columns are objects/strings, so I tried to convert them using the following function :

```
def str_to_bool(s):
    if s == 'True':
         return True
    elif s == 'False':
         return False
```

But it raises the following error :

```
"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".
```

Comment: What do you see for `df.dtypes` ? If you have Boolean series, you should prefer `~df['col_A']` to `df['col_A'] == False`. If you don't, you need to convert your series to Boolean.

Comment: they're objects, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

First convert your series to Boolean, for example via `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
cols = ['col_A', 'col_B']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.eq('True'))
```

Then apply your logic, noting `~` can be used to negate a series:

```
df.loc[~df['col_A'] & ~df['col_B'], 'col_C'] = "abc"
```

Or by de Morgan's law:

```
df.loc[~(df['col_A'] | df['col_B']), 'col_C'] = "abc"
```